# React Native this2.'function' is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a problem with my React Native Component.

```
sayHi = (s) => {
    console.log('hey' + s)
}

renderListItem(item, i) {

    return (
        <TouchableOpacity
            key={i}
            style={styles.listItem}
            onPress={() => { this.sayHi('bob') }}>

        <Text>{item}</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    )
}

render() {
    this.sayHi('patrick')

    const { list } = this.props

    return (
        <View>
        {list.map(this.renderListItem)}
        </View>
    )
}
```

In `renderListItem` I get an error **_this2.sayHi is not a function**.

Searched online but most posts do not fit my situation; I took a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43218451/react-native-this-function-is-not-a-function) but I already have an arrow function so it's not a context problem.

The function console logs just fine in the `render()`.
I tried to bind the `this` in the constructor but I still get the error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) executes the callback in a different context so `this` isn't correctly bound. Per the documentation:

> #### Syntax
>
> ```
> var new_array = arr.map(callback[, thisArg])
> ```
>
> #### Parameters
>
> [...]
>
> **`thisArg`**
>
> Optional. Value to use as `this` when executing callback.
>
> [...]
>
> If a `thisArg` parameter is provided to `map`, it will be used as callback's `this` value. Otherwise, the value `undefined` will be used as its `this` value.

You can pass `this` context as the second argument to `Array#map`:

```
{list.map(this.renderListItem, this)}
```

Or, use `Function#bind` directly:

```
{list.map(this.renderListItem.bind(this))}
```

Finally, you could use an arrow function:

```
{list.map((item, i) => this.renderListItem(item, i))}
```

Though I would choose the first option personally.

Comment: Couldn't you also use a fat arrow function and call the method within said function?

Comment: This worked. But why did THIS work but binding in the constructor did not?

Comment: @MichaelLyons Sure; you could also `bind` it.

Answer (score 1):

Just for reference, the `bind` solution mentioned in the comments by Andrew Li can be accomplished by changing this line

```
{list.map(this.renderListItem)}
```

to this

```
{list.map(this.renderListItem.bind(this))}
```